# Postgres select highest of ordered settings with default (sql fiddle)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Say I have a few settings scoped to users, but always having a default (when user_id is NULL):

`settings`:

```
   name   | value  | user_id | confirmed
________________________________________
fav_drink | coke   |  NULL   |   NULL     # the default
fav_drink | pepsi  |    1    |   false
fav_drink | sprite |    1    |   true
fav_band  | elvis  |  NULL   |   true     # the default
fav_band  | beatles|    1    |   false
fav_sport | hockey |  NULL   |   true     # the default
```

And what I want to do is get all settings for a user, grouped by name, preferring (1) confirmed true, (2) confirmed false, or (3) the default setting resulting in:

```
    name   | value  | user_id | confirmed
________________________________________
fav_drink | sprite |    1    |   true
fav_band  | beatles|    1    |   false
fav_sport | hockey |  NULL   |   true
```

How do I construct a query in Postgres to accomplish this? Something like (and I realize this is sketchy pseudocode):

```
SELECT * from settings
WHERE user_id = 1 OR user_id IS NULL
GROUP BY name
MAX(
  ORDER BY (
    CASE
      WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL AND confirmed = true THEN 1
      WHEN user_id IS NOT NULL AND confirmed = false THEN 2
      WHEN user_ID IS NULL THEN 3
    END
  )
)
```

(I'm using postgres 9.x)

> [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f0fbe/3)

Answer (score 1):

based on logic that false is 0, true os 1 and null is coalesced to -1

**updated**

```
t=# with a as (
SELECT name, value, user_id, max(coalesce(confirmed::int,-1)) over (partition by name), coalesce(confirmed::int,-1)
from settings
WHERE user_id = 1 OR user_id IS NULL
)
select name,value,user_id,coalesce::boolean::text
  from a
where max= coalesce
order by 1;
   name    | value  | user_id | coalesce
-----------+--------+---------+----------
 fav_band  | elvis  |         | true
 fav_drink | sprite |       1 | true
 fav_sport | hockey |         | true
(3 rows)
```

here user_id for fav_band is null (not like in OP) because `elvis` has confirmed true and beatles false, thus true is "first"

Comment: that's awesome! How would that work if a default setting had confirmed set to true? (I updated my question above to include that scenario)

Comment: But why would a default ever be set to true?  Your whole premise was that `NULL` is the marker for the default.

Comment: I don't understand from the structure how I distinguish confirmed eq true deliberately from confirmed eq true by default. I suppose in such case you would need another column to tell the difference or so

Comment: I put it in a SQL fiddle, but it does not appear to be working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f0fbe/2

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find use of these data easier if you think of this as a view and build it up out of multiple tables: one that is `activities` with `activity, default_name (foreign key)`; another `activity_names` that is `activity (foreign key), activity_name`; a third that is `users` with `user_id` and other data; a fourth that is a join table `choices` for `user_id, activities, activity_name, and confirmed`. Note that the reciprocal foreign keys make initializing the tables a little tricky, but it's possible to postpone the referential integrity check.

```
SELECT users.*, activities.activity, 
       COALESCE(activity_name, default_name), confirmed
FROM activities NATURAL JOIN activity 
     LEFT NATURAL JOIN (users NATURAL JOIN choices)
WHERE user_id = 1
ORDER BY confirmed DESC NULLS LAST;
```

The only downside is you will get blanks in the User data for activities with no confirmation (default choice). This can be fixed. But first I suggest you consider how to normalize your tables.